# Finding variance of $Z = X + \sum_{i=1}^{X}Y_i$

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, variance

> Let $X$ be a random variable such that $X\sim Poi(λ)$ and $Y_i\sim Poi(μ)$ independently. $Y = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{X}Y_i$. Let $Z = X + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{X}Y_i$  be the total number of people. Find $Var(Z)$.

$$Var(Z) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2Cov(X,Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2[E[X]E[Y]-E[XY]]$$

$Var(X) = \lambda, E[X] =  \lambda, E[X^2] =  \lambda^2+ \lambda$ and $E[XY] = \mu[ \lambda^2+ \lambda]$.

How do I find $Var(Y)$?

The answer should be $Var(Z) = \lambda(1+3\mu+\mu^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) i.e.
$$
\text{Var(Z)}=E(\text{Var}(Z\mid X))+\text{Var}(E(Z\mid X))\tag{0}.
$$
First note that
$$
E(Z\mid X)=E(X\mid X)+E\left(\sum_{i=1}^XY_i\mid X\right)=X+X\mu=X(1+\mu)\tag{1}
$$
since
$$
E\left(\sum_{i=1}^XY_i\mid X=x\right)=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^xY_i\mid X=x\right)=x\mu
$$
for each value of $x\in\mathbb{N}$ where we used independence of the $Y_i$ from $X$ in the final step.

Hence
$$
\text{Var}(E(Z\mid X))=(1+\mu)^2\text{Var}(X)=(1+\mu)^2\lambda.\tag{2}
$$
Next we note that
$$
\text{Var}(Z\mid X)=X\mu\tag{3}
$$
since
$$
\text{Var}(X+\sum_{i=1}^XY_i\mid X=x)=\text{Var}(x+\sum_{i=1}^xY_i\mid X=x)=\text{Var}(\sum_{i=1}^xY_i)=x\mu
$$
where we use independence in the second last inequality. Hence
$$
E(\text{Var}(Z\mid X))=\mu\lambda\tag{4}
$$
Combining $(0)$, $(2)$, and $(4)$ we get that
$$
\text{Var}(Z)=\mu \lambda+(1+\mu)^2\lambda=\lambda(1+3\mu+\mu^2)
$$
as desired.